# How to loop dataframe by year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to loop dataframe by year.
For example my df is 2006-7-1 to 2021 length and 8 columns(A-H columns), index is datatime.
In this time,
df['A']['2006'] like that,

```
date
2006-07-01 00:00:00    1
2006-07-01 00:05:00    2
2006-07-01 00:10:00    3
2006-07-01 00:15:00    4
```

df['A']['2006'] is one of the answer i want, but df['A']['2007'],df['A']['2008']...,df['A']['2021'] is all of them.

But I don't know how to loop by year by year 2006-2021, because we cannot write df['A']['i'].
So, please rent me your knowledge.

Comment: Do you want to filter your dataframe by year?

Comment: I want get df['A']['2006'],df['A']['2007'],df['A']['2008']...
But in this time, I cannot use loop because df['A']['i'] meaning str i.

Comment: i added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a column in the dataframe and then loop through it as follows

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
```

Else you can try splitting the string and then extracting the year.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column for `Year`:

```
df['Year'] = pd.DataFrame([i.year for i in df['Date']])
```

Then filter your dataframe using that column:

```
df['A'][df['Year'] == 2007]
```

This will give you all rows with year equals to 2007.

Comment: yes, but now time index is datetime so I cannot add year columns.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If it is in `datetime` format, then you can use `.year` to extract year of datetime.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Sorry,  I don't know-how apply to index.
Now, I use df.index.year and resolved.